# Graph Search on OWL ontology

Tags: python, owl, ontology, knowledge-graph, owlready

I used Owlready2 in python to to create OWL ontologies. Recently, I have come across articles which refers performing BFS on the ontologies created using Protege. How to perform DFS/BFS on the entities in such ontologies ?

Comment: the question would be which edges would  be relevant or even more interesting, what would be the edges in your graph? Just the taxonomy? This all affects "how"

Comment: Yeah.. I want to make the search on the Taxonomy such that I get all the super classes too (hierarchical path).